# How to configure Hibernate C3P0 pool

Tags: mysql, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I had an issue with hibernate connection pool causing the disconnection of the mysql session.
So i make some googling and i used the C3P0 technology as i found to fix this problem but the bug still persist: the connection is lost after 8hours:
[image: mysql timeout issue]

Here's my hibernate configuration file:

```
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statement">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1;</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>


    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/cabinet?characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

And here's my POM file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cabinet</groupId>
  <artifactId>cabinet</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description></description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.16.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
      <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-sitemesh-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.bootstrap</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-bootstrap-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is there any configuration property to correct or a dependacy  to add?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your c3p0 configuration is ignored. I think you have two different hibernate-core versions, one from hibernate-annotations 3.5.0-Final and one from hibernate-c3p0.4.3.4-Final. Remove the hibernate-annotations 3.5.0-Final dependency because annotations are already included in hibernate-core since v3.5 Your hibernate-c3p0 4.3.4.Final dependency will add hibernate-core 4.3.4.Final.

Comment: Thank you i will test it and tell you the result

Comment: I try it,it works on "SELECT" but when i perform an "INSERT" the same error happened and in the log i found :   [http-bio-8080-exec-6] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver.